# Creating a new site in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, site-creation

If I was to create a new site within my currently installed SharePoint 2010 setup, would all of the features be the same as the others? If I have a site that has a broken search feature, will that carry over to the new one or will they have their own setups that they follow?

I am new to the SharePoint world and I am trying to create my own site with SharePoint defaults.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a new site collection using the OOTB templates (team, publishing etc), it come with default settings. A Site collections is independent then other site collections, have own storage quota, Permission settings, own data, Own owner or admins. You can make changes to the site collection which will stay within same site collection and will not effect other site collections.

But this site will consume all the available service applications available to the web application in which you created new site collection.

Note: we are talking about the site collections not the subsite within a site collection.

Read this to understand the concept: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262410.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 1):

In the SharePoint the site structure and features has hierarchy

**Web Application**

It can consume all the service applications and has it`s own features can differ from the other web application

**Site Collection**

A web application can contain more than one site collections which we can activate the different features based on usage but all the site collection consumes the web application features.

**Site**

A site collection can contain more than one site and site features can be maintained differently from another site. But all the sites can consume the parent site collection and web application features.

If you want to create sites with same structure and features you can create them as a template and new sites can be created from your custom template.